# View "open file descriptors"

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, unix, go

I have a webpage where the backend is written in Go and running on Ubuntu, and after a certain amount of days and activity, like clockwork, the goroutine will throw a 'panic' and start giving 502 proxy errors. The error I'm getting in Go is "too many open files."

After doing some research, I feel that I've narrowed the issue down to having too many "open file descriptors." I have read different proposed solutions which seem to have varying results for different people. That is all fine, but if I wanted to actually *view* these supposedly open file descriptors in realtime so that I can actually pinpoint what these "files" are how would I do that? I ask this because rather than try to guess as to which parts of my Go program are causing this I'd like to see if I can narrow things down even further (possibly to a MySQL socket that's not closing properly, or an OS file also not closing properly, etc.)

Comment: Theres isn’t really much to do in `go`, use whatever facilities your OS provides to view open files.

Comment: @JimB I hope it didn't seem like I was implying that the solution needed to be in Go. I figured it would be something in Ubuntu. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted?

Comment: I imagine it’s because there’s no programming related question here. How to list open files should should be something easily found with a little research. Simply putting the title of this post into google returns a multitude of resources.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `lsof` command (Linux) to "list open files". There will be a lot of output so it's good to filter the output by using options. `lsof -p <PID>` might be useful if you know the PID of your process. Use the `ps` command to find the PID.